# Finding the duplicate using Row Number in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have written an SQL query which actually finds the duplicate elevation from the table along with other unique columns. Here is my query. I want to convert that into pyspark.

```py
dup_df = spark.sql('''
SELECT g.pbkey,
       g.lon,
       g.lat,
       g.elevation
FROM DATA AS g
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT elevation,
          COUNT(elevation) AS NumOccurrences
   FROM DATA
   GROUP BY elevation
   HAVING (COUNT(elevation) > 1)) AS a ON (a.elevation = g.elevation)
''')
```

Comment: what is wrong with your current way of doing it ?

Comment: Performance is the only concern.
Will going to run it on Terabytes of data.

Comment: but you are currently doing it in pyspark .... so I do not understand what you expect !

Answer (score 0):

On Scala can be implemented with Window, guess, can be converted to Python:

```
val data = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 3).toDF("elevation")
val elevationWindow = Window.partitionBy("elevation")

data
  .withColumn("elevationCount", count("elevation").over(elevationWindow))
  .where($"elevationCount" > 1)
  .drop("elevationCount")
```

Output is:

```
+---------+
|elevation|
+---------+
|3        |
|3        |
+---------+
```